# Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 2287

Tags: centos, yum, repository

When I excute the:

```
yum clean all
```

I get the below Error:

> Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 2287

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you posted is bad advice. You should not remove the yum pidfile or killing the yum process, as this can cause inconsistencies to the package installation status, and mess up your package manager.

The best way is to wait for yum to finish. Eventually it'll release the lock and you'll be able to run `yum clean all` or whatever yum command.

If you want to have yum run only manually, disable `yum-cron` and `yum-updatesd`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by:

```
rm -f /var/run/yum.pid
```

then execute the:

```
yum clean all
```